# What is the correct way to create white-space on a page with CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm creating a site with, instead of different pages, one page with continuous scrolling where the links point to anchor points further down the page...

I've been creating space between the 'content areas' on the page with line breaks in the HTML (
 etc) but that seems awfully antiquated and just 'wrong'... is that the best practice way of doing it?

Cheers!

Comment: Whitespace comes in numerous different forms. A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Sorry, we cannot teach you basic CSS here. Complete a basic CSS tutorial please (MDN has good resources). Before asking a question again, please be sure to study our help section!

Answer (score 0):

Try `min-height:100%` on your content areas. This should force them to be at least one window-height tall.

Answer (score 0):

HTML paragraphs? The space between them can be determined with `margin-top` or `margin-bottom`.

```
<p>
Content A
</p>
<p>
Content B
</p>
```